# Reading iPhone UDID through Safari

Tags: iphone

I am trying to read iPhone UDID through Safari browser and below address is a manual how to make it hapeen.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/profile-service/profile-service.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505-CH2-SW26

I thought I should use some kind of PHP but, the language that they describe is not PHP.

here is the one of the codes.

```
world.mount_proc("/enroll") { |req, res|
HTTPAuth.basic_auth(req, res, "realm") {|user, password|
    user == 'apple' && password == 'apple'
}

res['Content-Type'] = "application/x-apple-aspen-config"
configuration = profile_service_payload(req, "signed-auth-token")
signed_profile = OpenSSL::PKCS7.sign(@@ssl_cert, @@ssl_key, 
        configuration, [], OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY)
res.body = signed_profile.to_der

}
```

What kind of language is this?

Comment: That's ruby, using WEBrick (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WEBrick)

Comment: Just to let you know Apple has deprecated the UDID so you might not to invest too much effort in it.

Comment: I wonder why they wrote ruby on their manual. It seems really hard to get UDID like http://whatismyudid.com

Comment: @Cœur - prior comment removed.